# How can I check the version of a Lottie file?

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I am building a react native app using expo and trying to use a couple lottie files using the lottie-react-native library. When I use the iOS simulator the files load fine, but when I try to run the app on my actual iPhone I get this warning:

"ReactNative.NativeModules.LottieAnimationView.pause did not have a corresponding prop defined
in the mock provided to SafeModule"

I know that expo relies on Lottie v2 so v3 files will cause the app to crash, but is it normal for the Lottie animations to work on the simulator but not the phone? And is there a way for me to check if an animation is v2? I can't seem to find any kind of indication of version when browsing the animations.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: what sdk version? can you provide a reproducible example? the latest expo sdk (41) updates to the latest version of lottie-react-native, so any file should be supported. it sounds like the error you are seeing is unrelated and may occur as the result of having an incorrect lottie-react-native version installed

Comment: My sdk version was the issue. I was using version 40. All the files load fine now, thank you! When I upgraded my sdk it said a number of my existing packages did not update. The app seems to be working fine but do you know if I'll have to reinstall those packages manually? Thanks again!

Comment: expo upgrade only handles upgrading known packages (things in the expo sdk). anything outside of the expo sdk we leave alone. you may not need to do anything to update them, it's just a warning to let you know that they may need to be updated